# Postgres not using Enum index to filter

Tags: postgresql

I have following table.

```
create table my_table
(
    id               bigint generated always as identity
        primary key,
    match_request_id text             not null,
    asset_type       asset_type       not null,
    created_at       timestamp with time zone default now(),
    updated_at       timestamp with time zone
);

create index my_table_asset_type_type_idx
    on mydb.my_table (asset_type);
```

Here's definition of my enum `asset_type`

```
SELECT enum_range(NULL::asset_type)

Result:

{B_GEO,B_LOCATION}
```

My table is having ~500 Million rows. Out of which 80% belong to `B_GEO` and rest belong to `B_LOCATION`. When I query table like below it doesn't seem to be using index at all always using Seq Scan, which of course takes a lot of time. Wondering if I am missing something very obvious here?

```
EXPLAIN  analyse
select * from mydb.my_table where asset_type= 'B_GEO';

Result:

Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..15622383.34 rows=399039159 width=125) (actual time=0.012..157888.342 rows=398513460 loops=1)
  Filter: (asset_type = 'B_GEO'::asset_type)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 94628941
Planning Time: 0.073 ms
Execution Time: 176045.579 ms
```

Comment: Use SET enable_seqscan TO off; and check your query plan. But there is no guarantee that an index scan is faster, it has to read the index and part of the table.  It depends on your hardware. When it is faster, you can optimize the configuration file to do it right

Comment: You data has *80% (asset_types) belong to B_GEO* and the only predicate being *asset_type= 'B_GEO';*. This means you will retrieve 80% of the rows in the table. A sequential scan is likely to be vastly **faster** then an index lookup. A sequential scan will require 1 i/o operation per block (read the block), an index scan 2 (or more?) i/o operations per block (read the index, then read the block). Now an index when predicate is `B_LOCATION` would be a may vastly different story, but it still retrieves 20% of the rows which could put it over the threshold where an index lookup is faster.